# XAML binding allows accessing static member by instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There's a common localization technique for WPF/Silverlight apps which involves a viewmodel wrapper around `.resx`-generated files. All bindings reference a property of the same instance of this wrapper, so a single `NotifyPropertyChanged` on this property automatically refreshes the entire UI.

For example, this is the `Locale` class:

```
public class Locale: ViewModelBase
{
    public LocalizedStrings Strings {get;} = new LocalizedStrings();
    public UpdateLocale()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Strings));
    }
}
```

And this is the binding:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ns:Locale x:Key="Locale" />
</Application.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locale}, Path=Strings.MyString1" />
```

All fields of the `LocalizedStrings` generated by .resx compiler are static.

This means you cannot do `new Locale().Strings.MyString1` in C# code and should use `LocalizedStrings.MyString1` instead, but in the binding it surprisingly works.

The question is, why? Is it the right way or there's a better approach?

Comment: well, binding is not making a "new" but an association to existing...so why not.

Comment: @GCamel the point is, you can't access `MyString1` on an *instance* of `LocalizedStrings` in C# - you need the type name itself. The `new` operator here is just an example of getting this instance.

Comment: ho,, i don't know what is in LocalizedStrings, but seems to be like dynamics...so normal

Comment: "The question is, why?" Simply because the WPF designers have built it like that. A Binding uses reflection, and it simply looks for non-static and static properties.

Comment: @GCamel no, `dynamic` doesn't allow accessing static fields by instance either

Comment: @Clemens contradicting an established behaviour just because "why not"? I expected some justification, like a common usage case which can only be implemented with this hack, etc.

Comment: Which "established behaviour"? The way you access static properties in C# hasn't got much to do with how property path resolution works in WPF data binding.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Localization) is a library you can try.